# React Native setState not causing rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm a complete beginner at react native and now I'm stuck with an update problem. I'm using `react-native-paper` and `typescript`.

In my app, I want to press a button and then the text field should change its text.

The problem is somehow at the button, or the called function because in the console log its always `"before: true after:true"` or `"before: false after:false"`,
but what I expected is `"before: true after: false"` or `vice-versa`

I've also got a second Text View which is not shown at all.

Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

My index.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import App from './src/App';

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <App />
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => Main);

My MyNavigation.tsx (which contains currently my whole app).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, Text, Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph, Banner } from 'react-native-paper';
import { View, Image, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class MyNavi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.setUnConnected = this.setUnConnected.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'viewcamera', title: 'View', icon: 'remove-red-eye' },
      { key: 'viewsettings', title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings' },
      { key: 'viewhelp', title: 'How-To', icon: 'help' },
    ],
    visible: true,
    connected: false,
  };

  _handleIndexChange = index => { this.setState({ index }); }

  setUnConnected = function () {
    console.log("before: " + this.state.connected);
    this.setState({ connected: !this.state.connected });
    console.log("after: " + this.state.connected);
    console.log("--------------");
  };

  ViewRoute = () =>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 40 }}>

      {/* --------- This text field does not get updated -------------*/}
      <Text>connected: {this.state.connected ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>

      {/* --------- This text field is not shown at all ------------*/}
      <Text>
        {this.state.connected}
      </Text>

      <Button icon="camera" mode="contained" onPress={this.setUnConnected}>
        Press me
      </Button>

      <View style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' }}
          style={{ marginTop: 40 }}
        // onLoad={() => this.setState({ connected: true })}
        />
      </View>
    </View>

  SettingsRoute = () => <Text>Settings</Text>;

  HelpRoute = () => <View></View>

  _renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    viewcamera: this.ViewRoute,
    viewsettings: this.SettingsRoute,
    viewhelp: this.HelpRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        navigationState={this.state}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here,

```
setUnConnected = function () {
    console.log("before: " + this.state.connected);
    this.setState({ connected: !this.state.connected });
    console.log("after: " + this.state.connected);
    console.log("--------------");
};
```

`setState` is `async` function and it takes some time to update the state. It does not block execution of next statements. So you will always get the previous state only for both the `console.log`.

To get the actual updated value, you should use [callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) in setState.

```
setUnConnected = function () {
    console.log("before: " + this.state.connected);
    this.setState({ connected: !this.state.connected }, () => console.log("after: " + this.state.connected); );   //Now you will get updated value.

    console.log("--------------");
};
```

For this,

```
{/* --------- This text field is not shown at all ------------*/}
<Text>
   {this.state.connected}
</Text>
```

`this.state.connected` is either `true` or `false` (Boolean) which will never be shown on screen. If you still want to see the value on screen, then you can use this `hack`.

```
<Text>
   {this.state.connected.toString()}
</Text>
```

---

**Update**

From the [docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/1.0/bottom-navigation.html),

> Pages are lazily rendered, which means that a page will be rendered the first time you navigate to it. After initial render, all the pages stay rendered to preserve their state.

Instead of this,

```
_renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    viewcamera: this.ViewRoute,
    viewsettings: this.SettingsRoute,
    viewhelp: this.HelpRoute,
});
```

You should use this version of `renderScene`,

```
_renderScene = ({ route, jumpTo }) => {
  switch (route.key) {
    case 'viewcamera':
      return <ViewRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} connected={this.state.connected} setUnConnected={this.setUnConnected}/>;  //Here you can pass data from state and function to your component
    case 'viewsettings':
      return <SettingsRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
    case 'viewhelp':
      return <HelpRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
  }
}
```

Your complete code should look like this,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BottomNavigation, Text, Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph, Banner } from 'react-native-paper';
import { View, Image, WebView } from 'react-native';

const ViewRoute = (props) =>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 40 }}>

    {/* --------- This text field does not get updated -------------*/}
    <Text>connected: {props.connected ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>

    {/* --------- This text field is not shown at all ------------*/}
    <Text>
      {props.connected.toString()}
    </Text>

    <Button icon="camera" mode="contained" onPress={props.setUnConnected}>
      Press me
    </Button>

    <View style={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' }}
        style={{ marginTop: 40 }}
      // onLoad={() => this.setState({ connected: true })}
      />
    </View>
  </View>

const SettingsRoute = () => <Text>Settings</Text>;

const HelpRoute = () => <View></View>

export default class MyNavi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.setUnConnected = this.setUnConnected.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        index: 0,
        routes: [
            { key: 'viewcamera', title: 'View', icon: 'remove-red-eye' },
            { key: 'viewsettings', title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings' },
            { key: 'viewhelp', title: 'How-To', icon: 'help' },
        ],
        visible: true,
        connected: false,
    };

    _handleIndexChange = index => { this.setState({ index }); }

    setUnConnected = function() {
        console.log("before: " + this.state.connected);
        this.setState({ connected: !this.state.connected });
        console.log("after: " + this.state.connected);
        console.log("--------------");
    };

    _renderScene = ({ route, jumpTo }) => {
        switch (route.key) {
            case 'viewcamera':
                return <ViewRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} connected={this.state.connected} setUnConnected={this.setUnConnected}/>; //Here you can pass data from state and function to your component
            case 'viewsettings':
                return <SettingsRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
            case 'viewhelp':
                return <HelpRoute jumpTo={jumpTo} />;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BottomNavigation
              navigationState={this.state}
              onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
              renderScene={this._renderScene}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, 
now the console log is correct and the second Text field is shown,
but unfortunately, both text fields are still not updated when I press the button, any idea about that?

Comment: Which button, `Press me`?

Comment: For this `{this.state.connected ? 'true' : 'false'}` you are always getting `false`, is it what you mean to say?

Comment: yes the press me button, exactly .. its always false

Comment: When you press button your second Text field showing correct value, i.e. true ?

Comment: no, it shows "connected: false" on the first line and "false" on the second

Answer (score 0):

State Updates May Be Asynchronous [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

So You cannot test your `console.log` in this way. Use the callback function of `setState` method as follows,

```
this.setState({ connected: !this.state.connected }, () => {
        console.log("after: " + this.state.connected);
        console.log("--------------");
    });
```

Hope this will help you.